# De Turck trick on mean curvature flow

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, parabolic-pde

I am reading the book Lecture on mean curvature flow by Xi-Ping Zhu.

Suppose $M^n$ is an n-dimension smooth manifold and $X(x,t):M^n \rightarrow R^{n+1}$ be a one-parameter family of smooth immersion. Metric and the second fundamental form on $X(x,t)$ is defined as $$g_{ij} = (\frac{\partial X }{\partial x_i},\frac{\partial X }{\partial x_j})\,\,\,\,h_{ij}= (n(x,t),\frac{\partial^2 X }{\partial x_i\partial x_j})$$
And the covariant derivative of vector $v$ is defined by 
$$\nabla_j v_i = \frac{\partial v_i }{\partial x_j} + \Gamma^i_{jk}v_k$$
By setting $$\frac{\partial X }{\partial t}=H n$$
Using the Gauss equation and the Weingarten equation, the author further calculate that 
$$g^{ij}\nabla_i\nabla_j X=g^{ij}(\frac{\partial^2 X }{\partial x_i\partial x_j}-\Gamma_{ij}^k\frac{\partial X }{\partial x_k})=g^{ij}h_{ij}n=Hn=\frac{\partial X }{\partial t}$$
Later he used the De Turck trick to make this equation become strictly parabolic. But I think
$$\frac{\partial X }{\partial t}=g^{ij}(\frac{\partial^2 X }{\partial x_i\partial x_j}-\Gamma_{ij}^k\frac{\partial X }{\partial x_k})$$
is already strictly parabolic. what is the purpose of the trick?
Thank you so much.

Comment: You may be careful about degenerate system and non-degenerate system

Comment: You mean that the coefficients may be zero at some time?

Comment: Mean curvature flow is invariant under diffeomorphism. That is, the equation is invariant under tangential perturbation. This means some of the eigenvalues of the symbol of the linearization are zero and so it is not strictly parabolic. It is degenerate parabolic. The degeneracy of mean curvature flow is addressed in section 2 of Gage and Hamilton's paper "The Heat Equation Shrinking Convex Plane Curves": https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214439902

Comment: I think there's a calculation in the book which expand $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ and you will also see second order derivative of $X$ from the $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ term.

Comment: I got what you mean @JohnMa ,thanks

Comment: Do I have to expand $\overline{\Gamma^k_{ij}}$ again to see the equation given by the trick is really strictly parabolic?

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $p\in M$ the symbol on some $\xi$ direction is given by $\sigma(\xi,p) = g^{ij}\xi_i\xi_j - g^{ij}\Gamma_{ij}^k\xi_k = |\xi|^2_{g} - g^{ij}\Gamma_{ij}^k\xi_k,$ and if you choose $g^{ij}\Gamma_{ij}^k\xi_k = |\xi|_g^2,$ the symbol is not an isomorphism.